# Anyway to get Eclipse to convert string to String?

Tags: java, eclipse, string

I know I'm just being lazy, but I was wondering if there's a way to get eclipse to automatically convert string to String? Normally program in c# where this isn't an issue and in Java its catching me out a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not exactly the solution you are looking for, but if you hit CTRL+Space, after typing several characters, you can let Eclipse complete for you with the right case. You can also create a template (Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor-> Templates) for string, so `String` will be a first suggestion when you type `string` (But you still have to hit CTRL+Space).

Comment: its not when you're developing an Android app